# django unique model with one to one relashionship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have 2 models. each of them can have int_number via one-to-one relashionship with IntNumber model.
So i need to do IntNumber.number unique for them(user and group should not refer same IntNumber). Extra lines are omitted.

```
class Group(models.Model):

    int_number = models.OneToOneField(
        IntNumber, 
        related_name='int_number', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )


class User(AbstractUser):

    int_number = models.OneToOneField(
        IntNumber, 
        related_name='int_number', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        )


class IntNumber(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

Comment: you need to define onetoonefield for group and user in `IntNumber` class instead defining int_number as onetoonefield in both classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put user and group as foreign key inside IntNumber so when ever Unique IntNumber is generated you can explicitly assign a user and group to it.

```
class IntNumber(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    user =   models.ForeignKey(User) 
    group =  models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Note: You can add null=True to user and group if you want to generate intNumber only for 1 of them